# Three linked problems : Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function and Module 'myApp' is not available

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I got these three problems, which I think are linked. I read a lot of Stackoverflow posts, and Google it since 2 days, but because I'm working with the ionic creator, I didn't find a proper answer...

The curious fact is I can run and use my app except one MainCtrl function, it works, but I still have these errors messages :

---

**Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.**

---

**Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/ng/areq?p0=MainCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined**

---

**Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'LoadingCtrl' is not a function, got undefined**

---

Here is my code, I'm sure it's a little mistake but I can't figure it out :

```js
// Here is the module declaration

var myApp = angular.module('app.directives', []);

// The first controller's

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicPopup', '$timeout', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout) {
  
$scope.createPopUpService = function(){

var newTemplate = '<div>Hi</div>';  
  
var myService = $ionicPopup.show({
        template: newTemplate,
        title: 'Test',
        scope: $scope,
        cssClass: 'popJoinService',
        buttons: [
              { text: '<b>Cancel<b/>',
                type: 'button-assertive'
              },
              {
                text: '<b>OK</b>',
                type: 'button-positive',
                onTap: function(e) {
                    console.log("Hello");
                  }
              }
            ]
          });
};
}]);

// The second controller's

myApp.controller('LoadingCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {
  $scope.show = function() {
    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: 'Loading...',
      duration: 3000
    }).then(function(){
       console.log("The loading indicator is now displayed");
    });
  };
  $scope.hide = function(){
    $ionicLoading.hide().then(function(){
       console.log("The loading indicator is now hidden");
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<ion-view title="HTML1" style="background-color:#93E693;">
  <div ng-app="app.directives">
    <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)" ng-controller ="LoadingCtrl">
                <ion-refresher-content
                      pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
                      pullingText="Pull to refresh"
                      refreshingSpinner="circles"
                      refreshingText="Refreshing...">
                </ion-refresher-content>
    </ion-refresher>
  </div>
  
<!-- I also tried this : ng-app="myApp" and ng-app="" but it seems the change as no effect on the result-->
<!-- Because it is ionic creator, I can't add scripts like usually -->
  
  <div ng-app="app.directives" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <button class="item-avatar button  button-small button-calm  button-block icon-left ion-android-add" ng-click="createPopUpService()">test button</button>
  </div>
  
</ion-view>
```

Comment: create a plunker with full code and have you refered the script file in indx.htm where your defining your app and controllers

Comment: You cannot have multiple `ng-app=".."` attributes, angular only bootstraps one automatically.

Comment: I just tried plunker (first time to me) and found an "{" error in the html file, but still I don't know how to fix these errors... :(

Ok, so devqon should I just add one global ng-app="app.directives" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it without punctuation.

```
var myApp = angular.module('yourAppName', []);
```

Try the body or html code.

```
<body ng-app="yourAppName">
```

or

```
<html ng-app="yourAppName">
```

myApp is variable and applies to Javascript.

```
var myApp = angular.module('yourAppName', []);
myApp.controller('MainController', function ( $scope, $rootScope ){
 //Controller code
});
```

Comment: Arf, if I global add an <html ng-app="yourAppName"> or <body ng-app="yourAppName">, and try to run my app, I have a blank white page. :/

Comment: Not required. However, the module name and the NGAPP value should be the same.

Comment: Not required. However, the module name and the NGAPP value should be the same.

var myApp = angular.module('yourAppName', []);

myApp.controller('MainController', function ( $scope, $rootScope ){
//code is here
});

<div ng-app="yourAppName" ng-controller="MainController"></div>

Comment: Thanks you are here to help me, because I'm going to turn crazy with this thing... @_@ I still have this error : 

- ionic.bundle.js:26799 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'LoadingCtrl' is not a function, got undefined -

I really don't see where this mistake could be write...